# Do the memory that I use in my app get clean after termination? even the leaks? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, memory, ios, termination

Do the memory that I use in my app get clean after termination? even the leaks?

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

Yes. However with the task switching in iOS4 and the fact that your app is no longer closed when a user presses the home button, it's more important than even to control your memory usage a fix leaking code.